# Should I use SQLite for automatically build a list of banned IPs of comment spammers?

Tags: php, sqlite, automation, thread-safety, spam-prevention

I am using a simple yet effective anti-spam system at a comments module which seems to be working flawlessly for more than a year now.

Since it is capable of recognizing automated comment spam attempts, I am thinking of extending this security module with an ability of adding the offender IPs to a blacklist automatically.

Do you think that I should use PHP's SQLite for this, or should I stick to MySQL (which I'm already using at the site)?

Is there a difference at all between the two database systems in this regard?

Comment: I've got to ask:  if the anti spam system has been working **flawlessly** for a year now, why do you need to start banning the ip addresses?

Comment: "Because I can." :) Seriously, I am just experimenting and I see no reason that automated spammers should be allowed to make repeated attempts to spread their messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to extend something that already uses a DBMS, stick to that DBMS. SQLite is as good as MySQL for a project like this, but I wouldn't mix both DBMS in the same module, if it's what you're worrying about.

Comment: I agree. SQLite would be perfect for this but it's kinda like having a toilet in your bathroom and wanting to add a urinal to it because it's more suited to peeing.